# How does recursive functions keep count when searching for maximum depth of binary tree javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, binary-tree, recursive-datastructures

```
 var maxDepth = function(root) {
     const recursion = (n) => {
         if (!n) return 0;
        
         let left = recursion(n.left)
         let right = recursion(n.right)
         return left > right ? left + 1 : right + 1
     }
     return recursion(root)
 };
```

When calling the recursion function, how does it keep count? I've seen a lot of other ways to find the maximum depth of a binary tree and all the recursive functions keep count by themselves. Can anyone please explain how this is working please? how does add 1 to function call work?

Here is another search method

```
  maxDepth() {
    if (!this.root) return 0;

    function maxDepthHelper(node) {
      if (node.left === null && node.right === null) return 1;
      if (node.left === null) return maxDepthHelper(node.right) + 1;
      if (node.right === null) return maxDepthHelper(node.left) + 1;
      return (
        Math.max(maxDepthHelper(node.left), maxDepthHelper(node.right)) + 1
      );
    }

    return maxDepthHelper(this.root);
  }
```

this one was part of a binary tree class method

Comment: What do you mean by "*how does it keep count?*"? It just counts the recursive call levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask, "how does add 1 to function call work?" Notice that `maxDepthHelper(...)` returns a number. So, what's going on is that the function call's *result* is a number, and that result is what is being incremented by 1. So, if in a particular case `maxDepthHelper(...)` produced 6, then `maxDepthHelper(...) + 1` is just 7.

To your more general question, "How does it keep count?" It doesn't. The call stack will contain many recursive calls to `maxDepthHelper` and many of those calls will execute `+ 1` on the return value. Those additions pile up, and ultimately produce the final result. Same idea here:

```js
const count = (n = 0) => {
   if (n < 1000) {
       return count(n + 1)
   }
   return n
}

count() // 1000
```

Nothing is "keeping track" here. The `n` variable is passed and its value accumulates as the call stack gets larger.

Comment: ```
var maxDepth = function(root) {
     const recursion = (n) => {
         if (!n) return 0;
        
         let left = recursion(n.left)
         let right = recursion(n.right)
         return left > right ? left + 1 : right + 1
     }
     return recursion(root)
 };
```
so in this example the variable "left" holds the count of function calls? if it is, what is counting the calls or how is the number generated?

Comment: Within any individual function call, the relevant value may be the `0` number literal, or may be held by `left` or by `right`. The point is that there is no variable *tracking* the overall sum of these values. All the numbers are `return`-ed to the caller, and the caller increments them by one, and then returns the result to *its caller* and so on, and so on, an indefinite number of times, until exhausting the call stack - and that very last returned value is the final result of the computation.